# How to manage or convert extremely large program

Tags: ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access business critical database that was originally created in the 90's and has been enlarged and upgraded up to Access 2007 at this point.  We have been using this database as a front end for a custom written ERP system essentially.  We have moved most of the data over to an SQL server long ago, but we are still using MS Access as a front end.  AS the project grows, we have a full time developer, we have started having stability problems and extremely frequent crashes of unknown causes.

As an example: 1 time out of 10 or so, a certain form will crash if I change the data in 1 specific field. There is no code firing at the time, the data is in a local temporary table that typically only has 5 rows most of the time.  If I change the data in the table nothing goes wrong, but if I change it on the form Access will hard crash and dump me to the desktop.  There are other examples I could provide of unexplained crashes

I am looking for advice on where to go at this point -- the access front end has all of the business logic for running our company essentially so I can't just abandon it.  Ideally we would re-write the entire front end in some other language.  The problem is that as a small company we don't have the resources to re-write the entire system in anything resembling a good time frame, and don't have the cash flow to pay someone else to do it.  My ideal solution would be a conversion of some sort from the access front end to another end point -- whether web or local windows -- but my searches here and on google make that seem like a non-starter.

So essentially every avenue I look at seems to be a dead-end:

- We can't find the source of the crashes to stabilize our current system,
- We can't stop production in our current system for as long as it would take to re-write it,
- We can't afford to pay someone else to write a new system,
- Automated conversion tools seem like a waste of money

Are there other options or which of the options that I have thought of seems best?

Comment: Rewriting is probably going to be your best solution. I would split it up into smaller pieces that could be released over time until the entire app is completed.

Comment: Is the front end in a shared location, or does each user have his own copy of the front end? Have you tried creating a fresh Access 2007 database and simply copy pasting all of the forms and modules? I had some unexplainable issues with one of my larger systems, and, surprisingly, just copying them into a fresh aacdb file solved my issues. Also, is the front-end an aacdb or an aacde?

Comment: each user has a separate front end. -- we create a fresh database on each release -- every month or so.

Comment: Sorry, I just revised my comment. Have you complied it into an aacde, or are you just using aacdb files for the front end?

Comment: we have two use cases -- our shop has accde's and our office uses accdb.  We are having stability issues in each.

Comment: Also, you may want to have a look at this and see if you violate any of the constraints here. It appears there are some limitations to the front end (i.e maximum of 1000 modules, etc). Run through this checklist and see if there's anything that jumps out at you. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-specifications-HA010030739.aspx     I have read that a compiled accde is generally more stable than an aacdb, but since you're having problems in both, it must be something else. Check out that article on the limiations of access - it applies to the front end as well.

Comment: Did you do Compact and Repair for the Access DB file? I find that helps sometimes with performance if the MDB file becomes twice as small.

Comment: Have you decompiled and / or imported your front-end into a completely fresh database at any stage? That can often help with odd problems.

Comment: I would also have a look into the network to make sure no packets or anything are being dropped. I've had access crash just when the network was under heavy load before.  Maybe play around with the ODBC driver, as well?

Comment: To answer a few of these questions:  to the best of my knowledge we aren't over the limits of Access at this point -- but we may be close in a few areas.  All front-ends are set to compact and repair each shut down, and they are all re-created every couple of months.  We also decompile, recompile, and then import into a new front end on every update -- typically once a month.

Comment: Can you tell us whether crashes are consistent with data you tried to enter? Does it always crash when you enter/select a specific value? Can you provide some working/crashing data samples?

Comment: some are fairly consistent.  An example:  On a form that is used daily by multiple people, if I change a value that is already entered it will crash.  However, that only happens for me -- the 3 other users of that form can update existing values with no problem.  We have no code running on this form automatically -- there is a save button that is manually triggered.  another example -- our timeclock form, used 4 times a day by all 50 employees, will crash on 1 or 2 computers on an average day.  Code is calling an update query after update pushing the current time / EmpID to SQL server.

Comment: @user1341514 - check whether your Region and Language windows settings (Control panel > Region and Language) are the same as the other 3 users that do not experience issues. If you are entering a date and your region is English (United states) the date should be in the M/d/yyyy format. If your region is English (Canada), the format is dd/MM/yyyy. This happend to me so many times... very annoying problem.

Comment: I have verified that each of us have the same language and region set.   -- the field in question is a currency field, if that is relevant at all.

Comment: which version of Access are you using?  Do you have all the service packs installed?  Which version of SQL Server is running as the back end.

Comment: @user1341514 hmmm I am running out of ideas, Regional Settings really fit the profile there... it still can be an issue. Go to Regional Settings window and click on ***Additional settings***. Compare all the values for Numbers and Currency tabs for PCs that work and don't work with the form. If that doesn't work, are the computers on the same network? Crash happens ONLY when you enter the same amount?

Comment: sorry haven't checked in a while -- this question may be dead now but I still want to respond as I appreciate all the thought put into this.  Versions: Access many on 2007 and 1 copy of 2013, both versions have problems 2013 is worse.  SQL is 2008.

Comment: George, I went back through and confirmed all of the fields in the Regional Settings / Additional Settings.  All are the same -- all computers are running in the same building on the same network.

Answer (score 1):

We have an enterprise level program with an Access front end and an SQL Server back end.  I wonder if it might not help to split the program up into different pieces for diagnostics.  For instance if you have Order Entry and Inventory Management you could have one front end for each function.  *(Yes I can hear the howling in the background but if it was only for the purpose of diagnosis maybe it would help... )*
You can also export the Access Database objects to text files and then import them into a fresh new database to get rid of weird errors in some occasions.

Comment: He may have to leave it in split front ends. Judging by his comment lower down, he may be pushing the limits on his front-end file. I referred him to an article above that details some of the limitations. If importing into a fresh database doesn't work, I suspect that he needs to downsize or split his current application into multiple smaller applications.

Comment: we have 3 different front ends -- from Full / Engineering only / Shop Access -- which is very stripped down.  File size is 80 M.  can grow to 100 M before compact.

Comment: Is there one front end that crashes more frequently?  I don't think that 80 Mb is that big a file to work with.  It seems that if you can track exactly where the problems are then you can come back with more specific questions about the exact place it crashes.  I hope that you can get your problems resolved.

Comment: The shop Access crashes the most often -- it is running on the most computers as well.  I haven't been able to determine a good 'crashes per user hour' calculation though =D

Comment: do you have standardized error catching so that you could turn on logging to see if an error is being thrown or what kind it is before crashing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess I will rephrase the basic issue here. If you have two Computing Science graduates on staff then they should have long ago anticipated that they reached the limits of Access. I fail to see this as any different than an overworked, oven in a restaurant that now have too many customers or a delivery truck that does not have the capacity to deliver goods to customers.

Since funds don't exist to re-write then your staff failed to put aside funds on a monthly bases to deal with this situation and now your choices as a result of this delayed action to deal with this growing problem places you in a difficult situation.

The computing science people you have on staff should have long ago seen this wall and limit you hit coming. In my experience is with most CS people is they consider Access rather limited, and thus even MORE alarm bells should have been ringing here and this means even less excuse exists for you to be placed in this unfortunate predicament.

So, assuming the computing science staff you have are well maintaining this application (and I graciously accept this is the case), then then a logical conclusion is this application has reached or exceeded the limits of Access. As noted such limits should have been long ago anticipated.

As you well point out that funds now do not exist for a re-write, then few choices exist without such funds.

However, you case may not be so bad since we NOW know you have experienced developers on staff. Given this case, then my suggestion would be to consider breaking out modules or small manageable parts and features one at a time from the application and having your well trained and experienced developers build either a web interface, or perhaps even using  something like .net if you wish to stay 100% desktop. So this "window" of opportunity is a great chance to consider a change in architecture)

Since the data limits are SQL server and NOT Access, then both applications (existing access front end) and the new parts can BOTH well and easy operate on the same data. As you do this, you then break out and remove the existing parts from the Access application. This would suggest you eventaully return to accetable stability in the Access applicaiton. At that point , you could continue, or stop to save funds.

As noted, without funds to re-write, then the only choice is to find some means to free up SOME limited resources on a monthly basis to solve this problem.

At the end of the day, the solution to this problem is more resources, but without such resources then few technical choices and options exist here. Based on the information given so far YOU have made it clear you don't have resources here. However, the solution to this problem here requires resource allocation and planning.

In other words a technical fix to this problem without resources allocated is not likely an available option for you.

I apologize sincerely for not being able to give you a technology solution here, but this looks to be a solution that will require resources to be allocated to the problem and no simple shortcut or trick or magic silver bullet exists here.